# Why is JavaScript of the HTML from page2 loaded into page1 not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, same-origin-policy

im trying to load html from page2 into page one but its JavaScript won't work, is this same origin policy? if it is how do i bypass this?

Page1:

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>page 1 test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#thisandthat').click(function() {
    $("#hide").toggle('fast');
    $("#cont").load('testpage2.html #res')
     $("#unhide").toggle('fast');
     console.log ()
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="">
<input id="thisandthat" name="test but" type="button" value="Button" />
<div id="hide" style="background-color:#050; width:100; height:100;">this and other things</div>
</div>
<div id="cont">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page2

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>page 1 test</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#thisand').click(function() {
    $("#unhide").toggle('fast');
    alert ('im in')
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="res">
<input id="thisand" name="test but" type="button" value="Button" />
<div id="unhide" hidden="" style="background-color:#09F; width:100; height:100;">i     apppear</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, javascript needed from page2 is present on page1. Please help.

Comment: once you fix the issue mentioned in the answer, the javascript will still likely execute too early. That's generally why you shouldn't include additional javascript using .load.

Comment: It is a CORS issue only if page 2 is from another domain or subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the id selector in your `$("#cont").load('testpage2.html #res')`

jQuery will only load that section of page 2, therefore no Javascript is loaded. If you remove the id selector it will load the whole page including the Javascript.

`$("#cont").load('testpage2.html')`

Alternatively, you can place your Javascript within the `res` div, then that should work.

On a side note, you're missing various line ending semi colons in your code, which is not good.

Comment: Im loading #res because i only want that div, not the whole page2.

Comment: I assumed as much, as I mentioned above, if you want to only load `#res` and still load the Javascript, you'd need to place the Javascript within the `res` div. However a better idea would be to load a single Javascript file that did all your biddings in one place rather than page specific scripts.